# How to scroll up and down in EFI shell

Tags: shell, uefi, scrolling, efi

When you boot in UEFI mode, you can be loaded to EFI shell.
In EFI shell you can type `help -b` to see available commands by paging them as in more command. But I do not know how to scroll back up. I cannot make a screenshot, because it is a real machine. And I always run command again to output information that was slided up.
So is there a possibility to scroll up in EFI shell?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can scroll. Use <kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>Shift+PgUp</kbd> to scroll it up. I have checked it in EFI shell v1 and v2 in virtual machines and in a real machine, all variants are working.